# How do I toggle word wrap on and off in VS Code, wrapping at a specific column?

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap

In VS Code, you can toggle word wrap on and off easily. However, I can't figure out how to toggle it based a column.

By default, I want word wrap off, so I have `editor.wordWrap` set to `off`. At times, though, I want to toggle it on for a specific editor, and I want it to wrap at column 78 (`editor.wordWrapColumn` set to `78`). As far as I can determine, though, "View: Toggle Word Wrap" only changes `editor.wordWrap` from `off` to `on`. What I want would be a way to:

- default `editor.wordWrap` to `false`
- toggle it from `false` to `wordWrapColumn` and back again

I checked and there's no extension that will do this.

This is as of VS Code 1.20

Comment: I have found an extension, called Rewrap, which kinda sorta meets the need that I was trying to fulfill originally, which was an on-demand word wrap. It does a hard wrap, though, which is not exactly what I was looking for originally (I was looking for a soft wrap originally).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version of VS Code you were using and I'm not a pro with it by any means but I found the following article when I was researching another issue and thought it might help.

[Visual Studio Code February 2017 - Editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_editor)

Because "links are not answers," the relative content is as follows:

[image: Snip of VS Code Editor wordWrap changes in version 1.10]

Comment: Thanks, Mark -- I've added the version number. The documentation above illustrates nicely the design flaw in all of this: they have a toggle command for a value that has more than two values.

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension recently to toggle custom VS code settings, called Setting Toggle.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ho-Wan.setting-toggle

If you have any issues, please let me know.